# UIImage: make an image look like a shadow

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

How do I make a UIImageView show the "shadow" of the the UIImage in it?

I have a dog.png file, but I just want to show the shadow of the UIImage so when I press a button it reveals the real image of the dog. so I want something like this:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a20f1cca1f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a20f1cca1f.png)

and after I press the button It shows the real Image:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1516ffbbe.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1516ffbbe.gif)

Please give me a hand on this.

Comment: Why not make another image? Which is the usual approach.

Comment: Because this is just a test, the real app has more than 500 images and I am not going to to make 1k of images, the app is gonna be to heavy.